# How to read QCheckbox state from QTableWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am adding a `QCheckBox` item to one of the cells in my `QTableWidget` using the following:

```
cell_widget = QWidget()
chk_bx = QCheckBox()
chk_bx.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
lay_out = QHBoxLayout(cell_widget)
lay_out.addWidget(chk_bx)
lay_out.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
lay_out.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
cell_widget.setLayout(lay_out)
self.definedEventsTable.setCellWidget(row, select_column, cell_widget)
```

The variable `definedEventsTable` is a `QTableWidget`.

The above code works fine and the checkbox is correctly displayed on the GUI and is checkable. Nothing wrong there.

However, when I try to read whether or not it is checked, I cannot seem to be able to do so. Here is what I have tried:

```
self.definedEventsTable.item(row, select_column)
self.definedEventsTable.itemAt(row, select_column)
self.definedEventsTable.cellWidget(row, select_column)
```

Each of these return `None` and therefore cannot run `isChecked()`. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Apologies, it appears that the following is working. Clearly I fumbled around or something.

```
self.definedEventsTable.cellWidget(row, select_column)
```

However, it returns a `QWidget`. How can I get the `QCheckbox`?

Comment: Note: [`itemAt`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#itemAt-1) returns the item at the given **coordinates**, with reference to the viewport. The arguments are `x` and `y` for a given *point*, not rows and columns. Then, QCheckBox by default is always unchecked (like all QAbstractButton subclasses), so there's no need to set the state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cellWidget method returns the widget set in the cell, which in your case is "cellWidget" so there are several options to obtain the associated QCheckBox:

#### - Use findChild

```py
cell_widget = self.definedEventsTable.cellWidget(row, select_column)
checkbox = cell_widget.findChild(QCheckBox)
if checkbox:
    print(checkbox)
```

#### - Custom Attribute

```py
cell_widget = QWidget()
chk_bx = QCheckBox()
chk_bx.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
lay_out = QHBoxLayout(cell_widget)
lay_out.addWidget(chk_bx)
lay_out.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
lay_out.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
cell_widget.checkbox = chk_bx
self.definedEventsTable.setCellWidget(row, select_column, cell_widget)
```

Then:

```
cell_widget = self.definedEventsTable.cellWidget(row, select_column)
if hasattr(cell_widget, "checkbox"):
    checkbox = cell_widget.checkbox
    print(checkbox)
```

#### - Custom QWidget

```
class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.chk_bx = QCheckBox()
        self.chk_bx.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
        lay_out = QHBoxLayout(self)
        lay_out.addWidget(self.chk_bx)
        lay_out.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        lay_out.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
```

```
cell_widget = Widget()
self.definedEventsTable.setCellWidget(row, select_column, cell_widget)
```

Then:

```
cell_widget = self.definedEventsTable.cellWidget(row, select_column)
checkbox = cell_widget.chk_bx
print(checkbox)
```

Comment: Thank you very much